# CSS one div refuse to be scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://www.valleryarts.com/users/testing/guide.html

I am not sure why the div is not being scrollable, I already have overflow: scroll set. As you can see the channels is not being scrollable horizontal. I have my padding and margin set to cover the visibility of scrollbar. So I would like to have mouse or in mobile, touching to scroll.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Questions here are meant to be followed by code and in the purpose to be useful to the community in general so for future visitors too. Add some. Explain what you've tried and what's your exact issue. Fore more info see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refer to the [help].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There's a magic link to `[ask]` as well :)

Comment: @TJ Adorable! ;) never late to learn cool magic!!!

Comment: Dude, `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` works with a defined `height` and `width`. If I am correct, your code does not have `width` defined and even if it has, it is for the `guideouter` element which is the parent of the scrollable `div`, which means `#guideinner` has the same width as its parent. I hope the explanation helps. I would also prefer some kind of code that you have written to be posted along with the question so that it is easy to find a solution. Moreover, in Stackoverflow, questions are asked and answers/solutions are found. Proper questioning makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below classes

```
    .grid .wrapper {   
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    #guideinner {
        margin-left: 160px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;

    }

    #guideouter {
        margin-bottom: -50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        width: 6336px;
    }
```

Comment: My god! I spent few days trying to figure out where I went wrong. You just rearranged my css and now it works. Thank you so much!